# Why forEach does not exist on NodeListOf

Tags: javascript, typescript

My code:

```
    var checkboxes = this.element.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]") as NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement>;
    checkboxes.forEach(ele => {
        var key = ele.name;
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!this.isArray(data[key])) {
                var temp = data[key];
                data[key] = [temp];
            }
        } else {
            data[key] = [];
        }
    });
```

But I got an error:

> error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type
>   'NodeListOf'.

```
interface NodeListOf<TNode extends Node> extends NodeList {
    length: number;
    item(index: number): TNode;
    [index: number]: TNode;
}

interface NodeList {
    /**
     * Returns an array of key, value pairs for every entry in the list
     */
    entries(): IterableIterator<[number, Node]>;
    /**
     * Performs the specified action for each node in an list.
     * @param callbackfn  A function that accepts up to three arguments. forEach calls the callbackfn function one time for each element in the list.
     * @param thisArg  An object to which the this keyword can refer in the callbackfn function. If thisArg is omitted, undefined is used as the this value.
     */
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: Node, index: number, listObj: NodeList) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
    /**
     * Returns an list of keys in the list
     */
    keys(): IterableIterator<number>;

    /**
     * Returns an list of values in the list
     */
    values(): IterableIterator<Node>;


    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<Node>;
}
```

'NodeListOf' inherit from 'NodeList',and 'NodeList' has 'forEach'
 method,why 'forEach' does not exist on 'NodeListOf'?

Comment: Because it only exists on `Array`. Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here. Use `Array.from()` if you want to use `forEach`.

Comment: @jhpratt `NodeList` has a `forEach` method: [`NodeList.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is no guarantee `forEach` will exist on this type - it can, but not necessarily (e.g. in PhantomJS and IE), so TypeScript disallows it by default. In order to iterate over it you can use:

1) Array.from():

```
Array.from(checkboxes).forEach((el) => { /* do something */});
```

2) for-in:

```
for (let i in checkboxes) {
  if (checkboxes.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    console.log(checkboxes[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that answer 2 is working? I get the error: "Type 'NodeListOf<Element>' is not an array type or a string type.".

Comment: You are right, only for-in loop will work with TypeScript, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Honestly you *could* convert a NodeListOf to an array so that typescript will not complain about *nodelist*.forEach, but this is only solving the problem by adding unnecessary code. You can tell typescript to understand the native *nodelist*.forEach syntax by adding the **dom.iterable** library to your tsconfig.json. Here is an example of one of my tsconfig.json files.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./public/js/",
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "module": "es6",
  "target": "es5",
  "allowJs": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "rootDir": "src",
  "lib": [
    "es6",
    "dom",
    "dom.iterable"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "removeComments": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "public",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Not all browsers support *nodelist*.forEach so I would definitely polyfill it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: I had to also add the `"downlevelIteration: true` to `compilerOptions` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4947#issuecomment-295966266).  If you want to keep the emitted JS file size down, you can add [`tslib`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslib) along with the flags `importHelpers` and `noEmitHelpers`.